# DateListPlot inside DynamicModule updates continuously

Tags: bugs, dynamic

**bug fixed in 10.4.1**

Can any one try this code and see if it is updating continuously without changing the controllers:

```
data = MapThread[
     Prepend[#2, #1] &, {DateList /@ 
       RandomReal[
        AbsoluteTime[#] & /@ {{2015, 1, 1}, {2015, 12, 30}}, #], 
  RandomReal[20, {#, 5}]}] &@5;
DynamicModule[{i, ii},
 Column[{
   Manipulator[Dynamic[i], {2, 6, 1}],
   Control[{{ii, 3}, {3, 4, 6}}],
   Row[{Dynamic@
      DateListPlot[data[[;; , {1, i}]], PlotRange -> All, 
       ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> RandomReal[], 
       PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[]]],
     Dynamic@
      DateListPlot[data[[;; , {1, ii}]], PlotRange -> All, 
       ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> RandomReal[], 
       PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[]]]}]
   }]
 ]
```

If you remove one of the plots then the code works fine without problem.
If you use `Manipulate` and remove all controllers and `Dynamic` then the code will work fine.

Edit

there can also be several plots where some plots use the same manipulator symbol.

**Update:**

**I sent this case to wolfram and they have confirmed it is incorrect behavior and the case has been sent to  developers**

Comment: Does using TrackedSymbols ensure that the Manipulate will only reevaluate the object(s) depending on the tracked symbols when they actually change?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, that dose not help when you have several plots  where some plots use same manipulator symbol.

Comment: since you are adding new information in your comment, and therefore your question does not contain a minimal working example of what you want solved, I am voting to close

Comment: I see no continuous updating in v9.0.1 and v8.0.4 win 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this to put Mike Honeychurch's comment on record as an answer.

```
SeedRandom[42]; 
data = 
  MapThread[
    Prepend[#2, #1] &, 
    {DateList /@ RandomReal[AbsoluteTime[#] & /@ {{2015, 1, 1}, {2015, 12, 30}}, #], 
     RandomReal[20, {#, 5}]}] & @ 5;

plot = 
  DateListPlot[data[[;; , {1, #}]], 
    PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> RandomReal[], 
    PlotStyle -> Hue[RandomReal[]]] &;

DynamicModule[{i, ii},
  Column[{
    Manipulator[Dynamic[i], {2, 6, 1}],
    Control[{{ii, 3}, {3, 4, 6}}],
    Row[{
      Dynamic[plot[i], TrackedSymbols :> {i}], 
      Dynamic[plot[ii], TrackedSymbols :> {ii}]}]}]]
```

[image: plots]

No continuous updating of the plots in the above version.